# Request validation error on production, not on local

Tags: php, laravel-5

So i've search the farthest reaches of the internet and come up with nothing. Please help!

I am developing locally on my Mac, all is fine.

When I push the site to production (CentOS7 VPS) I get the following error:

BadMethodCallException in Validator.php line 3162:
Method [validatePublication] does not exist.

Here is my app/Services/Validation/CustomValidation.php

```

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class CustomValidation extends Validator {
 //added only for test
    public function validateCartRow($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
      $valid = (is_null(\Cart::get($value))) ? false : true;

      return $valid;
    }

    public function validatePublication($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
      $valid = (\PublisherAPI::publicationByID($value) == false) ? false : true;

      return $valid;
    }
}
```

```

Here is my app/Providers/ValidationServiceProvider.php

```

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Services\Validation\CustomValidation;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class ValidationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->validator->resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
        {
            return new \App\Services\Validation\CustomValidation($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
    //
    }
}
```

```

Here is my app/Http/Requests/Cart/addToCartRequest.php

```

```
namespace App\Http\Requests\Cart;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class addToCartRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'row_publication_id' => 'required|string|numeric|publication',
            'row_price_key' => 'required|string|numeric',
        ];
    }
}
```

```

This is the request that is failing on production. Again, I stress this is not a problem on my local Mac.

Any thoughts? I'm stumped...

Thanks!

UPDATE: Stack trace...

```
in Validator.php line 3265
at Validator->__call('validatePublication', array('row_publication_id', '4', array(), object(Validator))) in Validator.php line 485
at Validator->validatePublication('row_publication_id', '4', array(), object(Validator)) in Validator.php line 485
at Validator->validate('row_publication_id', 'publication') in Validator.php line 425
at Validator->passes() in ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait.php line 24
at FormRequest->validate() in FoundationServiceProvider.php line 41
at FoundationServiceProvider->Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\{closure}(object(addToCartRequest), object(Application)) in Container.php line 1031
at Container->fireCallbackArray(object(addToCartRequest), array(object(Closure))) in Container.php line 996
at Container->fireResolvingCallbacks('App\Http\Requests\Cart\addToCartRequest', object(addToCartRequest)) in Container.php line 648
at Container->make('App\Http\Requests\Cart\addToCartRequest', array()) in Application.php line 697
at Application->make('App\Http\Requests\Cart\addToCartRequest') in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 85
at ControllerDispatcher->transformDependency(object(ReflectionParameter), array(), array()) in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 59
at ControllerDispatcher->resolveMethodDependencies(array(), object(ReflectionMethod)) in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 42
at ControllerDispatcher->resolveClassMethodDependencies(array(), object(CartController), 'addToCart') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 144
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(CartController), object(Route), 'addToCart') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(CartController), object(Route), object(Request), 'addToCart') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\Cart\CartController', 'addToCart') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SessionTimeout.php line 58
at SessionTimeout->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(SessionTimeout), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: I have..

php artisan cache:clear, composer dump-autoload, deleted composer.lock, composer update, composer install,

Nothing so far. The pull worked fine, all the files match between local and production.

Anyone got a hint?

I thought it could be case sensitive namespacing or strict paths or something but I can't see an error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a filename in app.php when registering the service provider.

I missed it as on local, the filename was correct. However I have a merge-driver setup that I completely forgot about preventing app.php being merged with staging (because of the application URL), so the error persisted.

I think I need to move the application URL to an environment variable and load the relevant config, getting rid of the merge driver.

Thanks to the guys at Laracasts for helping me get to the bottom of this..

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/error-on-production-not-on-local