# Validation always fail in production but working in local in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I'm trying to test my API endpoints in production but it always return the `required` validation failure. But when I try in my local, it is working well. Please see details below.

**PeriodsRequest.php**

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
      'company_code' => 'required'
   ];
}
```

**Validation response**

```
{
    "message": "The company code field is required.",
    "errors": {
        "company_code": [
            "The company code field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

**api.php**

```
Route::get('company', CompanyController::class);
```

**Controller**

```
public function __invoke(PeriodsRequest $request)
{
    return (new Company)->getPeriods($request->validated());
}
```

**Postman screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Did you try to close and re open postman. It sometimes caches the result.

Comment: @gguney yes I tried it but it still returns the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Params and Body in Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60345726/what-is-the-difference-between-params-and-body-in-postman)

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden nope. I'm using get request so I need to use the Params instead of the body

Comment: Do you get the same result by going to the same route in your browser? Also check your request/response headers in browser for both local and production to see if there's any differences e.g. maybe a redirect you weren't expecting

Comment: @apokryfos when I tried to access using the production in the browser, it is redirecting to the homepage. But in my local, it returns the correct data. Any idea with this?

Comment: Are your local and prod environments same? (I could be wrong but sounds like a case sensitivity issue)

Comment: @user3532758 yes, they have same .env and configs except of course for the db credentials since I have to use the prod database

Comment: I do not mean .env file. I meant, is your local running on linux and production running on linux type of environment :) sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user3532758 I'm on a mac on local, and linux for the production

Comment: I do not have a definite solution, but I am still leaning towards case sensitivity. Mac is not case sensitive, but linux is, so there is a chance you have a case issue in a file name when you referenced. Maybe explore that path. A similar issue is documented here. Worth a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250995/request-validation-error-on-production-not-on-local

Answer (score 0):

**[Solution]**

Needed to configure the nginx like so:

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`

Reference:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/request-all-returns-empty-array-for-get-method-laravel-55?page=1&replyId=476661